# Lock object to remember another position

Tags: animation

Please advice on this on.

Let’s say I split one face from the cubes and make it it’s own object

But I want it to remember it’s original position (the 4 corner) to the cube.

So later during the animation I want the face to assemble back to its position to form/shape the cube.. hope it makes sense:

Please point me in a direction
Br Hamid

Comment: Consider using a  copy transform constraint on split face targeting  the original

Comment: I forgot to mention that the cube will be moving.. will the copy transform still work with that..

Comment: You can always place an empty object in position.